# HA, 1.1.1.7, Lurie

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

[image: Luire HA remark 1.1.1.7]

In this remark, Lurie states that applying proposition HTT 4.3.2.15 twice, we deduce that $\theta$ is a kan fibration.

How is this assertion deduced?

Comment: Proposition 4.3.2.15 is somewhat notorious for being opaque, but perhaps the discussion found [here](https://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/garcia.pdf) would help.